# jquery search a select option area

Tags: jquery, forms, search

Im trying to build a little web app that would send a message to multiple recipients.  At the moment i have a message box, a send button and a select box that is filled by a database query of our customers.  As you can imagine there is a long list of clients in the select options box.  I was hoping to put in another text box which would search in that text area for the client name and highlight it as you type.

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <input type="text" name="search" id="search" />
    <select name="select" size="20" id="select">
      <option 1>james</option>
      <option 2>johns</option>
      <option n>janes</option>
    </select>
```

Can anyone provide an example of jquery code like this, ive done quite a bit of hunting but havent turned up anything, and im not great with jquery :(

Comment: it is really hard to get what do you want

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [chosen plugin](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

**HTML**

```
<select name="select" multiple size="20" id="select" class="chosen-select">
   <option value="1">james</option>
   <option value="2">johns</option>
   <option value="n">janes</option>
</select>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(function(){
    $(".chosen-select").chosen({disable_search_threshold: 10});
});
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/6MHq6/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Well you need an `autocomplete` field for that, Twitter bootstrap  `TypeAhead.js`, which i s robust,easy to use and good in looks as well.

https://github.com/biggora/bootstrap-ajax-typeahead

**JQUERY CODE:**

```
    $('.typeahead').typeahead({
        source: data
    });
```

**LIVE DEMO:**

http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/p3wXs/69/

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use auto-completion. You can use [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) for that. Otherwise, interpreting your requirements it sounds like you want someone to type in a text area and fill choose from the select automatically. You can start with the following (see here for **[a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VBXkw/1/)**):

```
$('textarea').keyup(function()
{
    var text = $(this).val();
    var lastWord = text.split(' ').pop().trim();    
    if( lastWord )
    {
        $("select option").filter(function() {        
            return $(this).text() == lastWord; 
        }).prop('selected', true);
    }
});
```